# how can I check that two variables from different functions equal each other?

Tags: python

I'm trying to recreate space invaders(a very basic version of it), on my raspberry pi sense hat kit (8 by 8 pixel screen).

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from random import randint
from time import sleep
sense = SenseHat()
x = 4
y = 7
# g is the background color, p is player color, l is laser color, s is the color of the enemyships
g = (64, 64, 64)
p = (0, 255, 0)
l = (255, 0, 0)
s = (0, 0, 255)
sy = None
ly = None

sense.clear(g)
sense.set_pixel(x, y, p)
def moveship(event):
    global x, y, p, g, l
    if event.action == "pressed":
        if event.direction == "left" and x > 0:
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, g)
            x -= 1
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, p)
        elif event.direction == "right" and x < 7:
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, g)
            x += 1
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, p)
        elif event.direction == "up" and y > 0:
            ly = y
            for i in range(7):
                ly -= 1
                sense.set_pixel(x, ly, l)
                sleep(0.05)
                sense.set_pixel(x, ly, g)

def spawnEnemyShip():
    global x, y, g, s
    sx = randint(0,7)
    sy = y - 7
    for i in range(8):
        sense.set_pixel(sx, sy, s)
        sleep(0.5)
        sense.set_pixel(sx, sy, g)
        global ly
        if sy == ly:
            print("it works")
        else:
            sy += 1

sense.stick.direction_any = moveship
```

I can move the player ship left and right, move up on the sense hat joystick to fire the laser and spawn an enemy ship with "spawnEnemyShip". And I have been trying for easily a dozen hours total trying to figure out how to make the code know when the laser hits the same pixel as an enemy ship. Asking for help was a last resort because I wanted to try myself first but I've been at this brick wall for a while now and I can't make progress. The code above was my final attempt before asking.

Comment: Currently does the laser move upwards? I don't see anything here that would indicate that it would. But you can keep track of the laser positions and at each time step, check to see if the laser's position is out of bounds or if it hit an enemy by checking the color at where it should be in that time step.

Comment: Andrew that could work, it does move upwards. I think I would just need to check the pixel above it before it moves.

Comment: Tried it, I checked the pixel of the laser before it moves to see if that pixel's color is the same as the enemy ship, it didn't work.

Comment: Huh, it should work. Are you sure that the laser is moving upwards then? Maybe you can debug it by printing out the coordinates and the colors of everything the laser is passing and checking that against the locations of the aliens.

Comment: Will try that, I'm fairly new to python so I'm not that familiar with debugging methods.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok that worked, at first it wasn't that consistent because it would just miss the enemy ship due to them skipping over each other but I added more to the enemy ship to make the blue pixel stay there longer so hopefully they don't skip over each other like one out of a thousand times. If it isn't 100% then I just make the enemy ship 2 pixels long. I think I will leave the question open because I'd still like to know how to do my original request. But this workaround works for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods in these two that helped me solve it. Specifically my answer used global.
https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-pass-local-variable-from-function-to-another-function-in-Python
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-variables-from-other-functions-in-Python
Here is my program after solving my issue, the laser now hits the enemy ship and they both disappear.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from random import randint
from time import sleep
sense = SenseHat()
x = 4
y = 7
g = (64, 64, 64)
p = (0, 255, 0)
l = (255, 0, 0)
s = (0, 0, 255)
e = (255, 165, 0)
sy = None
ly = None
z = None

sense.clear(g)
sense.set_pixel(x, y, p)
def moveship(event):
    global x, y, p, g, l, s
    if event.action == "pressed":
        if event.direction == "left" and x > 0:
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, g)
            x -= 1
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, p)
        elif event.direction == "right" and x < 7:
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, g)
            x += 1
            sense.set_pixel(x, y, p)
        elif event.direction == "up" and y > 0:
            ly = y
            for i in range(7):
                ly -= 1
                color = sense.get_pixel(x, ly)
                if color == [0, 0, 248]:
                    global z
                    z = "yes"
                    print (z)
                    break
                else:
                    color1 = sense.get_pixel(x, ly)
                    sense.set_pixel(x, ly, l)
                    sleep(0.05)
                    sense.set_pixel(x, ly, g)
                    print("player", x, ly, color1)

def spawnEnemyShip():
    global x, y, g, s, z
    sx = randint(0,7)
    sy = y - 7
    for i in range(7):
        print("enemy", + x, sy)
        if z == "yes":
            print("it works")
            z = None
            break
        else:
            sense.set_pixel(sx, sy, s)
            sleep(0.3)
            sy += 1
            sense.set_pixel(sx, sy, s)
            sleep(0.3)
            sy -= 1
            sense.set_pixel(sx, sy, g)
            sy += 1
            sense.set_pixel(sx, sy, g)


sense.stick.direction_any = moveship
```